# Visual Studio crashes my laptop

Tags: freeze, troubleshooting, visual-studio

I bought a Compaq cq40 330tu laptop a month ago.  Its configuration is:

- Intel Core 2 Duo 2.0 GHz
- 2GB DDR2 RAM
- 160GB hard disk

I installed Microsoft Visual Studio a week ago.  When I try to open an ASP.NET solution my laptop hangs and stops responding.  I am using Windows XP SP2 as the OS.

Comment: And look at all the downvotes. Scares me the idea superuser may become like this soon. i.e. An hideous place

Comment: Could you provide some extra information using proper grammar and spelling? 

You know web pages don't have intellisense like VS has, nor are you sending a text message.

Comment: I'm assuming the downvotes are for poor punctuation, spelling, word choice, lack of relevant details (how does it hang, is it a hard lock? what version of visual studio? what steps has the OP tried to resolve the problem? Why isn't the OP running SP3? Can the OP get the project done using other tools?)

Comment: I would hope so, Tyler. But the downvotes came from stackoverflow. In fact there's been 2 upvotes on this question already since it arrived here. In any case you are absolutely right it's badly formulated. But then... why didn't they leave a comment instead of just downvoting out of... whatever motivated them to downvote. Anyways, human nature I guess.

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio [2002 (7.0)](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=C41D8159-B42F-4D06-A797-E510494976EE&displaylang=en), [2003 (7.1)](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=69d2219f-ce82-46a5-8aec-072bd4bb955e&displaylang=en), [2005 (8.0)](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=BB4A75AB-E2D4-4C96-B39D-37BAF6B5B1DC&displaylang=en) and [2008 (9.0)](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=FBEE1648-7106-44A7-9649-6D9F6D58056E&displaylang=en) all have a service pack release that fix numerous problems.  Perhaps you're running into something that's already been fixed.